# Вывод данных в RecyclerView из БД

Tags: android, recyclerview

Пишу приложение Словарь, который будет переводить слова с русского на английский и наоборот.

В БД есть две таблицы:

`TABLE_RUSOTHER` - перевод с русского на английский

`TABLE_OTHERRUS` - перевод с английского на русский

Переключение осуществляется по кнопке `btnReverseLang`. Изначально при открытии приложения должны отображаться данные из таблицы `TABLE_RUSOTHER` и переключатель должен быть так: Русский - Английский (он так и есть), но почему-то при запуске приложения отображаются данные из таблицы `TABLE_OTHERRUS`.

Я думаю что это из-за строчки `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_OTHER, bundle, this);`

Как правильно реализовать вывод?

Код MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, WordsAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    RecyclerView rvList;

    private TextView txtLeftLang;
    private TextView txtRightLang;
    private ImageButton btnReverseLang;
    private boolean isOtherRight;

    DBHelper db;

    private int currentLoader;
    final private static int LOADER_RUS = 0;
    final private static int LOADER_OTHER = 1;

    WordsAdapter wordsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        txtLeftLang = findViewById(R.id.txtLeftLang);
        txtRightLang = findViewById(R.id.txtRightLang);
        btnReverseLang = findViewById(R.id.btnReverseLang);

        txtLeftLang.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
        txtRightLang.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));

        db = new DBHelper(this);

        rvList = findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        wordsAdapter = new WordsAdapter(this);
        rvList.setAdapter(wordsAdapter);
        wordsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", "");

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_RUS, bundle, this);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_OTHER, bundle, this);

        btnReverseLang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                txtRightLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
                txtLeftLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));


                isOtherRight = !isOtherRight;

                if (isOtherRight) {
                    currentLoader = LOADER_RUS;
                    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
                } else {
                    currentLoader = LOADER_OTHER;
                    getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Word.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite) {
        String table;
        String fav;
        String toast;
        int currentLoader;

        if (isOtherRight) {
            table = DBContract.Entry.TABLE_RUSOTHER;
            currentLoader = LOADER_RUS;
        } else {
            table = DBContract.Entry.TABLE_OTHERRUS;
            currentLoader = LOADER_OTHER;
        }

        if (isFavorite) {
            fav = "0";
            toast = "Удалено из избранного";
        } else {
            fav = "1";
            toast = "Добавлено в избранное";
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBContract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITES, fav);
        long newRowId = db.myDataBase.update(table, values, DBContract.Entry._ID + "= " + id, null);
        if (newRowId == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        String filter = bundle.getString("filter");
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db, id, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        wordsAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        wordsAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        Cursor cursor;
        DBHelper dbHeler;
        final int loaderID;
        String filter;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DBHelper dbHeler, int id, String filter) {
            super(context);
            this.dbHeler = dbHeler;
            loaderID = id;
            this.filter = filter;
        }

        @Override
        protected Cursor onLoadInBackground() {
            switch (loaderID) {
                case LOADER_RUS:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getRusWords(filter);
                    break;
                case LOADER_OTHER:
                    cursor = dbHeler.getOtherWords(filter);
                    break;
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }

    private void refreshCursor(String str) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString("filter", str);
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(currentLoader, bundle, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(search);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                wordsAdapter.setFilterLength(newText.length());
                refreshCursor(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в методе `onClick()` строку `isOtherRight = !isOtherRight;` перенесите после блока `if` - у вас получается, что выводите на экран при одном состоянии переменной, а данные получаете изменив это состояние на противоположное. Нужно получить данные с этим же состоянием, а потом изменить его. Также инциализировать последним нужно тот лоудер, который будет выводиться на экран первым:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_OTHER, bundle, this);
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_RUS, bundle, this);

btnReverseLang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtRightLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang));
            txtLeftLang.setText(isOtherRight? getResources().getString(R.string.rus_lang):getResources().getString(R.string.other_lang));

            if (isOtherRight) {
                currentLoader = LOADER_RUS;
            } else {
                currentLoader = LOADER_OTHER;
            }
            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(currentLoader).forceLoad();
            isOtherRight = !isOtherRight;
        }
    });
```